# R code for the "reverse-half pyramid of odd numbers"

Tags: r

EDITED
How could I make a function in R program to get this result down below?
Each line of output starts with one or more spaces.

```
half_pyramid(1)
 1
.
.
.
```

I really can't get past this..

```
half_pyramid = function(n= scan()) {
  for (k in (2*n):1) {
    if (k %% 2 == 1) {
      for (i in 1:k) {
        for (j in (k-i):0) {
        i = as.character(i)
        cat(i)
      }
      cat("\n")
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: How should the result look for `half_pyramid(6)`, i.e., when you reach two-digit numbers?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I want the function to only work for odd numbers and when the input is a two digit number, for example, half_pyramid(11), the result would be _2121212121212121212121 __19191919191919191919 ___171717171717171717 ____1515151515151515 … ___________1

Comment: Please add this to the question with appropriate formatting. We are particularly interested in how you want to align two- and one-digit numbers in a half-pyramid.

Answer (score 4):

It's more efficient to do this with recursion rather than a multiply-nested loop

```r
half_pyramid <- function(n, leading = 1) {

  cat(paste0(c(rep(' ', leading), rep(2 * n - 1, n)), collapse = ''), '\n')
  if(n != 1) half_pyramid(n - 1, leading + 1) 
}
```

Testing:

```r
half_pyramid(1)
#>  1

half_pyramid(3)
#>  555 
#>   33 
#>    1

half_pyramid(5)
#>  99999 
#>   7777 
#>    555 
#>     33 
#>      1
```

It's not really clear what's supposed to happen when n > 5, since 11 has 2 digits and therefore takes up disproportionate horizontal space in the output. This would be the case whatever the solution used though.

<sup>Created on 2022-12-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>